# Merge 2 maps at specific index

Tags: sass

I was wondering if I can merge 2 sass maps at a specific index of the first map.

```
$numbers: (
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2,
    "three": 3,
    "six": 6,
    "seven": 7,
);

$more-numbers: (
    "four": 4,
    "five": 5,
);

@debug map.merge($numbers, $more-numbers); 
// ("one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3, "six": 6, "seven": 7, "four": 4, "five": 5)
```

Instead, I want:

`("one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3, "four": 4, "five": 5, "six": 6, "seven": 7)`

I tried with the list module functions `list.index()` `list.set-nth()` but it replaces the index

```
$index: list.index($numbers, (three 3));
@debug list.set-nth($numbers, $index, $more-numbers);
// "one" 1, "two" 2, ("four": 4, "five": 5), "six" 6, "seven" 7
```

Even if that worked I am not sure how I can convert it back to a map.

Edit because someone asked the reason behind my question..

I am experimenting with generating utility classes.

`u-padding-1: { padding: 0.375rem; }`

I have already a map with the values:

```
$padding: (
    "properties": (
        "-padding": padding,
    ),
    "directions": (
        null: null,
        "-horizontal": "-left" "-right",
        "-vertical": "-top" "-bottom",
        "-top": "-top",
        "-right": "-right",
        "-bottom": "-bottom",
        "-left": "-left",
    ),
    "values": (
        "-none":    0rem,
        "-tiny":    t.rem(t.spacing(tiny)),
        "-small":   t.rem(t.spacing(small)),
        null:       t.rem(t.spacing(base)),
        "-large":   t.rem(t.spacing(large)),
        "-huge":    t.rem(t.spacing(huge)),
        "-auto":    auto,
    ),
) !default;
```

Now instead of manually adding all the utility key value pairs in the $padding->"values"

```
"-0": 0,
"-1": 1,
...
```

I generate them with a while loop and merge them. That would not be an issue but I need these utility classes to be added just before the keyword values like auto, full, etc. for cascading reasons.

I don't want to add another key value pair to my map, for example

```
"keywords: (
    "-auto": auto,
    "-full": 100%,
    ....
),
```

because I also generate responsive classes and it gets messy.

This is an example of a partial file.

```
@use "sass:map";
@use "sass:math";
@use "../settings/index.settings" as s;
@use "../tools/index.tools" as t;

$margin: (
    "properties": (
        "-margin": margin,
    ),
    "directions": (
        null: null,
        "-horizontal": "-left" "-right",
        "-vertical": "-top" "-bottom",
        "-top": "-top",
        "-right": "-right",
        "-bottom": "-bottom",
        "-left": "-left",
    ),
    "values": (
        "-none":    0px,
        "-tiny":    t.rem(t.spacing(tiny)),
        "-small":   t.rem(t.spacing(small)),
        null:       t.rem(t.spacing(base)),
        "-large":   t.rem(t.spacing(large)),
        "-huge":    t.rem(t.spacing(huge)),
        "-auto":    auto,
    ),
) !default;

// Populate map with values
$margin-arithmetic-progress: ();
$m: 0;
@while $m <= (t.strip-unit(s.$global-baseline) * 5) {
    $converted: t.rem($m);
    $margin-arithmetic-progress: map.set($margin-arithmetic-progress, "values", "-#{math.div($m, t.strip-unit(s.$global-baseline))}", $converted);
    $m: $m + t.strip-unit(s.$global-baseline);
}

$margin: map.deep-merge($margin, $margin-arithmetic-progress);

@include t.generate-classes($margin);
@include t.generate-responsive-classes($margin);
```

Comment: What is your goal of doing that? Maps values could be accessed by their keys. Does the order is really important?

Comment: I edited my question about my goal for wanting to do that.